# Ionic Firebase and SQLite

Tags: sqlite, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm using SQLite in my project, but for Login I'm going to use Firebase.
Can I use the 2 databases in the application? And is it possible to sync them? The Login with the products etc that comes from the SQLite bank?  Thanks

Comment: Sqlite is client side persistence and Firebase is server-side. There is no reason why they cant work together.

Comment: Sqlite works great for local storage on the device, and is more of a client-side storage unit. Firebase is for your back-end and is made to store data indefinitely. You should have no problem implementing them together. In my apps I am using Sqlite3 for storing data on the device and my API calls store form submissions to my back-end database.

Comment: It is indeed possible to use Firebase Authentication with a local sqlite database, or with pretty much any other product/service that has an API. How to connect them depend on your use-cases and is a bit broad to answer on Stack Overflow. But give it a try, and if you get stuck: post a question with the [minimal steps/code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you guys. It was all I needed to know. =)